# android studio cannot resolve method(), ignoring import

Tags: java, android

I'm a total noob at android studio, and I have a (to me) weird problem. I have inserted a button in my XML document:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="127dp"
        android:text="SUM"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_row="15"
        android:layout_column="0" />
```

And in the java code I would like a to make it do something when i click on it. However in code (I know there is way too many import):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    R.id.button.onCliclistener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
            DO THIS WHEN CLICKED ON
        }
    });
}
```

BUT it says: Cannot resolve method() and Cannot resolve symbol, to the onCliclistener and ActionListener. And it says: unused import statement, to thier imports. It's probably a stupid question, but what am I doing wrong?

Nicolaj

Comment: There are so many mistakes in your code. See this example for button click : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making reference to your button in your `onCreate` method and then create an `onClick` method.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

  Button btn;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

      btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //Reference to the button

      btn.setOnClickListener(this); 
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     DO THIS WHEN CLICKED ON
  }
}
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: @ErikJhordanReyCaffrey For sure! I make it quickly and I forgot to put it. I edit my question now. Thanks for the alert!